# Setting up a gossip spy

Tags: solana-cli, validator

For someone not running a validator, what would be the best method to listen in on gossip, getting staked amount, block, etc. "solana gossip" is giving me some of that information but not all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, it basically sounds like you want all of the information (gossip traffic, newly created blocks, etc) that a validator has access to without running a validator. If you want all of this data in real time, then your only option is running a validator.

That being said, one item that may be of interest to you is that you can run a non-voting validator by passing `--no-voting` argument. This will save you the voting costs, but the hardware requirements of a non-voting node are essentially identical to that of a voting node.

I'd also encourage you to take a look at the [JSON RPC API](https://docs.solana.com/api/http) and see if the available information provided would be sufficient for your needs. If so, API access from one of the numerous providers might be a cheaper (and easier) route than managing your own node.

Comment: Thank you. Solana gossip gives me most of the information I wanted, however was hoping to get a bit more. Mainly stake weight. I will look into other methods

Comment: For stake weight, check out the `getVoteAccounts` method in JSON RPC API:https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getvoteaccounts

You can also query the same information with `solana validators` from the CLI. If you go this route, make sure you specify the appropriate network (ie mnb/testnet/devnet).